# How to run SQL query on click using conditional PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a room availability check page for a hostel and I am having an issue.

I have a database with a table named 'rooms' listing all type of rooms with these rows:

1. id [INT]
2. name (room type) [CHAR]
3. capacity (max capacity, not to be changed)[INT]
4. used (number of beds used, **I want to change this dynamically**!) [INT]

I created a code to generate the rooms list from the DB with PHP and **I want the "+" and "-" buttons to either add or remove one unit in the used column for a specific room. How can I do this?**

Here is my code:

```
           <!-- SOME HTML/PHP THAT WORKS -->    
            <?php if ($roomlist->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($room = $roomlist->fetch_assoc()) {
                $roomid = $room["id"]; ?>
              <div>
                <!-- SOME OTHER HTML/PHP THAT WORKS -->

                  // THE ISSUE IS BELOW, IT SHOWS THE CORRECT AMOUNT BUT $room["used"] DOES NOT UPDATE
                  <div>
                    Used: <?php echo $room["used"] . " / " . $room["capacity"] ?>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" name="remove" value="-" />
                    <input type="submit" name="add" value="+" />

                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
                      $remove_query = mysqli_query("UPDATE rooms SET used = used - 1 WHERE id = $roomid") or die(mysqli_error());
                    } elseif (isset($_POST['add'])){
                      $add_query = mysqli_query("UPDATE rooms SET used = used + 1 WHERE id = $roomid") or die(mysqli_error());
                    }

                    ?>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
              <?php }
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                } ?>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP needs to understand the life cycle of a PHP web page and how to use forms  and that is a whole tutorial not a simple answer

Comment: http://myphpform.com/php-form-tutorial.php

Comment: I am sorry, it was not my intension to offend, but from your code it is quite obvious that you jumped into the deep end and are having a little trouble swimming. Unfortunately SO is not supposed to be a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the action of your form to whatever the name of your code is (e.g., "rooms.php"), then move

```
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
    $remove_query = mysqli_query("UPDATE rooms SET used = used - 1 WHERE id     = $roomid") or die(mysqli_error());
} elseif (isset($_POST['add'])){
    $add_query = mysqli_query("UPDATE rooms SET used = used + 1 WHERE id = $roomid") or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

up to the top so it updates the table before you query the table to fill in the rest of the page, it should work.  Right now, your php is updating the table after the SELECT query to populate your page, so it doesn't appear to be updating.

I think a better tack would be implementing AJAX so your form updates the Used field without reloading the page.

Comment: I guess you missed all the other issues

Comment: I am a complete newbie but I'll try learning AJAX for that, I tried doing what you told me but I end up with a partially loaded page (the rooms don't appear anymore :/) Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @Krimou32 Dont bother, First learn how a web page with a form on it works. Tutorials, books, tutorials, books

Comment: @RiggsFolly  There's no need to be snarky.  I'm just trying to help him out a little.

Comment: But you totally missed that there are no `<input...>` fields in the `<form>`. I was just saying this was not necessarily the best question to be your first answer. The OP has no idea what they are doing and needs a full tutorial, not a bit of a nudge

Comment: Suggesting OP goes to AJAX is definitely a step to far, at least for now

Comment: Note I did not Downvote, what I thought was a poor answer! Maybe you too would benefit from starting by doing [the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as if nothing else it gets you a few extra rep points

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I figured out a way on my own in the end so I post it here for other people facing a similar issue to overcome it ;)

Here is the concerned part of the code in index.php:

```
<form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $roomid ?>&action=remove&used=<?php echo $room["used"] ?>&capacity=<?php echo $room["capacity"] ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="remove" class="minus" value="-" />
</form>
<form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $roomid ?>&action=add&used=<?php echo $room["used"] ?>&capacity=<?php echo $room["capacity"] ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="add" class="plus" value="+" />
</form>
```

And the code of update.php:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['used']) && isset($_REQUEST['id']) && isset($_REQUEST['capacity'])) {

    $roomid  = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $used = $_REQUEST['used'];
    $capacity = $_REQUEST['capacity'];

    if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'add') {
      if ($used >= $capacity) {
        header("location: index.php");
      } else {
        $newValue = $used + 1;
        $add_query = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `rooms` SET `used` = $newValue WHERE `ID` = $roomid") or die(mysqli_error());
        header("location: index.php");
      }
    } elseif (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'remove') {
      if ($used <= 0) {
        header("location: index.php");
      } else {
        $newValue = $used - 1;
        $remove_query = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `rooms` SET `used` = $newValue WHERE `ID` = $roomid") or die(mysqli_error());
        header("location: index.php");
      }
    }
}
```